Cors configuration?
from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
im working with anglular 16 on vs and java on intelliJ
my code works just fine with posman but i keep getting the same error
i tried adding the cors config and filter on my backend
package project.CORS;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import javax.servlet.Filter;


public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> corsFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new CorsFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registrationBean.setOrder(1); // set precedence
        return registrationBean;
    }
}

package project.CORS;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CorsFilter implements Filter{
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorsFilter.class);

    public CorsFilter() {
        log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}



response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin")); response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"); is insecure. Don't do it, or you'll likely expose your users to cross-origin attacks. More details at https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties

Default CORS filters happen earlier than custom request/response filters, so I m pretty much sure, that request does not even enters your class.
You have to configure SecurityFilterChain bean. You can research Internet and documentation to take a look how it should be configured. Documentation
But here is a small example of how it can be used in pet projects.
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationProcessFilter authenticationEntryPoint)
    throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationEntryPoint, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .cors()
        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()

        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/api/login", "/api/v1/users/register",  "/api/login/**", "/api/admin/login", "/api/public/**")
        .permitAll()

        .antMatchers("/api/**")
        .permitAll()

        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, ex) -> response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN))
        .authenticationEntryPoint(
            (request, response, authException) -> response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED));


    return http.build();
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(allowedMethods);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(allowedHeaders);
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", configuration);
    return source;
}


Offtop. Your postman works because CORS - is a browser security mechanism. Postman will bypass it by default.
